# Как добавить реквизит в справочник пользователей 1С?

Tags: 1с

Есть справочник пользователей. У пользователя в предприятии можно разрешить или запретить доступ на вход. И я хочу программно получить значение этого поля.

[image]

Но если получать пользователей с помощью запроса ниже, то в полученном списке пользователей у них не будет колонки со значением данного поля.

```
ВЫБРАТЬ 
| Пользователи.Ссылка 
|ИЗ
| Справочник.Пользователи КАК Пользователи
|ГДЕ
| Пользователи.Служебный = Ложь
```

Поэтому я хочу добавить данное значение в реквизиты справочника пользователей с помощью расширения, чтобы оно вычислялось при записи пользователя. Как это можно сделать?

UPD1:
`ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.ПолучитьПользователей()` тоже не имеет данной колонки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте конфигурацию, найдите в дереве объектов: Справочник - Пользователи (у Вас он может называться иначе);

Откройте Формы - ФормаЭлемента; Установите курсор на флажок, правый клик - Свойства

События: ПриИзменении - клик на лупу, для перехода к указанной процедуре;

Внимательно изучите что происходит в процедуре ...

```
&НаКлиенте

    Процедура ВходВПрограммуРазрешенПриИзменении(Элемент)
        
        Если Объект.ПометкаУдаления И ВходВПрограммуРазрешен Тогда
            ВходВПрограммуРазрешен = Ложь;
            ПоказатьПредупреждение(,
                НСтр("ru = 'Чтобы разрешить вход в программу, требуется снять
                           |пометку на удаление с этого пользователя.'"));
            Возврат;
        КонецЕсли;
```